# How can I merge values in one dictionary as an item to another dictionary created inside a "for" loop?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nlp, n-gram

I am struggling with lists, loops and dictionaries.

Basically, I have two 'levels' of dictionary. The first has as its key a word, and as the value the number of occurrences of that word within a given sentence. So like this:

`wordcount={'sort': 3, 'count': 3, 'wrap': 3, 'coin': 11}`

Next, I have a for loop that goes through a list of just these words, and for each one creates a dictionary with a number of additional attributes, namely that word's occurrence according to Google N-grams:

```
for word in wordlist:

      url =f"https://books.google.com/ngrams/json?content= 
      {word}&year_start=1965&year_end=1975&corpus=26&smoothing=3"
      sleep(1)
      resp = requests.get(url)

            if resp.ok:
                results = json.loads(resp.content)[0]
                results_clean = {key: val for key, val in results.items() if key == "ngram" or key =="timeseries"}
                timeseries = {key: results_clean[key] for key in results_clean.keys() & {'timeseries'}}
                timeseriesvalues= list(timeseries.values())
                timeseriesmean=np.mean(timeseriesvalues)
                ngramsonly = {key: results_clean[key] for key in results_clean.keys() & {'ngram'}}
                ngramsvalues = list(ngramsonly.values())
                results_nouns_final={"word": ngramsvalues, "occurrence_mean": timeseriesmean}
```

Basically, I want to append to `results_noun_final` that word's occurrence value from before. However, when I try to do so by adding the word's value from `wordcount` as a third item to this dictionary (as follows):

```
results_nouns_final={"word": ngramsvalues, "occurrence_mean": timeseriesmean, "count": wordcount.items()}
```

It is appending *all* words' counts, and giving me something like the following:

```
{'word': ['sort'], 'occurrence_mean': 5.319996372468642e-05, 'count': dict_items([('sort', 3), ('count', 3), ('wrap', 3), ('coin', 11)}
{'word': ['count'], 'occurrence_mean': 4.5438979543294875e-05, 'count': dict_items([('sort', 3), ('count', 3), ('wrap', 3), ('coin', 11)}
...etc.
```

Could anybody let me know where I am going wrong? My desired output would be something like the following:

```
{'word': ['sort'], 'occurrence_mean': 5.319996372468642e-05, 'count': 3}
{'word': ['count'], 'occurrence_mean': 4.5438979543294875e-05, 'count': 3}
```

Comment: "when I try to do so by adding the word's value from wordcount as a third item to this dictionary... It is appending all words' counts" ... well, yes, that's what `wordcount.items()` means. I don't think I understand the question. You have a `dict` called `wordcount`, and you want to look up the value corresponding to a specific key, yes? Surely you know how to do this? (Hint: what does `results_clean[key]` mean?) Surely you know how to figure out the key you're looking for? (Hint: maybe it has something to do with the `ngramsvalues`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `wordcount.items()`, you are getting *all* the items in the `wordcount` dictionary. You only want to access the count of `word`.
Try replacing the last line in your loop with:

```
results_nouns_final={"word": ngramsvalues, "occurrence_mean": timeseriesmean, "count": wordcount.get(word)}
```

`wordcount.get(word)` gives you the count of `word` from your dictionary. Using `.get()` returns `None` if the `word` is not in `wordcount`.

If you're sure every word exists in your dictionary, you could just use `wordcount[word]`.